# Saving data in multiple tables

Tags: cakephp

I have a `Products` table and a `Products_Prices` tables.
The `Products_Prices` table has these fields `product_id, size_id, price`

in ProductsController's add action I am getting the data like. The Product save is working

but i don't know that after saving the product how should I get the `ID` of newly created product and how to save the price info.

```
array(
    'id' => '',
    'name' => 'Pizza Salami',
    'description' => 'some description here',
    'active' => '1',
    'offered' => '1',
    'category_id' => '15',
    'Price' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'size_id' => '2',
            'price' => '5'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'size_id' => '3',
            'price' => '6'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'size_id' => '4',
            'price' => '7'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'size_id' => '5',
            'price' => '9'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-hasone-hasmany-belongsto)?

You can get the id with `$id = $this->Model->id;`

You can also use `$this->Model->saveAssociated($this->request->data);` to save multiple model data at once.

Answer (score 1):

If *saveAll* and *saveAssociated* doesnt work for inserting rows into table, you can use
`$this->ModelName->getLastInsertID();` to get last inserted id in your table Products.